# Cannot enable quota on web server

Tags: mount, fstab

I'm trying to enable quota on my web server but I've hit a snag.

`/etc/fstab` looks like this:

```
/dev/mapper/VG_Foo-LV_ROOT_FOO /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,usrquota,grpquota 0       1
UUID=bc697229-7704-4fb1-9289-2b230dc5706e /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/VG_FOO-LV_VAR_FOO /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/VG_FOO-LV_SWAP_FOO none            swap    sw              0       0
```

I get the errors below when I run the following commands:

```
#quotacheck -avugm
quotacheck: WARNING -  Quotafile //quota.user was probably truncated. 
Cannot save quota settings...
quotacheck: WARNING -  Quotafile //quota.group was probably truncated.
Cannot save quota settings...

#quotaon -avug
quotaon: Cannot find quota file on / [/dev/dm-0] to turn quotas on/off.
quotaon: Cannot find quota file on / [/dev/dm-0] to turn quotas on/off.
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

its normal for quotacheck to give these errors when reading an empty quota file for the first time. This should go away on checking after subsequent remounts.